# Redirecting http://domain.com/ to https://domain.com issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I know this is repetitively asked question but the thing is I can't even find the answer. Recently, we've decided to have https so we want to redirect everything. Upon checking on to the other domains, I saw that http://domain.com/accommodation/ redirects to https://domain.com/index.php. Can you please tell me what is something wrong with my codes?

For the root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /sample/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>


#IP Canonicalization Test with sample IP 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^222\.222\.22\.222
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#URL Canonicalization Test
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

For the public directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

#IP Canonicalization Test with sample IP 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^222\.222\.22\.222
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#URL Canonicalization Test
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Added this for assurance for redirection
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Peace!

Comment: You're rewriting everything that's not a file or folder to `index.php` this may trigger first and then your redirect rule may trigger for the rewritten URL.

Comment: # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
So this part is what triggering everything?

Comment: Try moving all rules that result in a redirect before this one to see if it works (also you should move all mod_rewrite rules within the mod_rewrite block)

Comment: thank you, let me go ahead and check this one first, thank you.